# What is the meaning of <layout version="1.0.0"> in package module layout xml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, system.xml

what is reffering this code `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` in `system.xml` and `<layout version="1.0.0">` in layout `custom_module.xml` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>` defines the xml document. While there already is a newer [1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/) Version you still will mostly see the 1.0 Version: https://www.ibiblio.org/xml/books/effectivexml/chapters/03.html

the layout tag is a Magento construct and I assume that its Version is 1.0.0 since the beginning of time, but was introduced to have the possibility to upgrade the layout definition over the time.